# Similar sentences, but one puts object in Nominative, the other in Akkusative

Tags: grammatical-case

I have two sentences in German. Both mean "I will keep the gum for myself".
They are:

1. Ich werde das Kaugummi selbst behalten.
2. Ich werde den kaugummi für mich behalten.

I don't understand why Kaugummi isn't in the accusative in the first sentence as well, since it's the direct object in both.

Comment: Keep in mind that "Kaugummi" kann be both neuter and masculine in German.

Comment: It is accusative case in both sentences. But the noun *Gummi* (and therefore als the compound noun *Kaugummi*) has two genders. It can be neuter (*Das Gummi ist schwarz. Ich sehe das Gummi.*) but also masculine (*Der Gummi ist schwarz. Ich sehe den Gummi.*)